# How to make button to remove value in mysql field?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, button

I am having difficulty making a button that removes existing values in MySQL database field. I have read up some information on it, some say use AJAX, but i'm not sure. What are your opinions? Can any Stackoverflow-er show me a method? I recognise I cannot use Javascript as it is on the client side and not server-side - but is there another way?

Comment: which technology you using ?? php?? or some other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create form first in html

```
<form method="get" action="delete.php">
   Enter id you want to delete : <input type="text" name="id">  
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

delete.php

```
<?php

    $dd=$_GET["id"];

    $c=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("mydatabase")
    mysql_query("delete form mytable where id=$dd");

    print "Remove successfully...";
?>
```

This upper code will remove the entries you want on clicking of submit button

Comment: I'll give this a try, thanks very much Shikhil! However, instead of Method="get" I'd use "post". because I'm sending data not requesting it.

Comment: query - typo of 'from'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the values from mysql database asynchronously then you'll need to use AJAX and that's the only option else if you are allowed to do it without refreshing the page then go with simple PHP.

Comment: but can I use the $_POST variable to remove it? Send a null value or ''? - without the need for AJAX - for this particular feature i'm making, refreshing doesn't matter.

Comment: yes you can use post variable to do it. but you should pass the id or any other unique data to delete that row or any other thing.
for example: localhost/myfile/delete.php?uid=2
on the delete page theirs a query passed: DELETE FROM `ids` WHERE uid='$_POST["uid"]';
now this query will delete the row where the uid is equal to 2.

Answer (score 0):

you need not to do it with ajax if u dont want. simple php is good enuf..

1. just make a form with a button field.
2. post a variable though it to your php.
3. connect with your database using update the dtabase as you want..

**Beware : One refresh would take place on this process as its not an asynchronous process. else you can choose AJAX**

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have a value that replaces the null value. This button i'm creating turns it to null. So therefore, this button will change the value to NULL, another function is called when it listens out for the change and then updates it to the stated default value.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a (post/get) request to a file on your server but i recommend you use AJAX to do this, the server side file will still look pretty much the same.

if you are using php for the back end the code would look like

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$res = $mysqli->query('your delete statement');
if(! $mysqli->errorno )
    header('Location:success url');
else
    header('Location:fail url?error=' . $mysqli->error')
```

you could use a link for you button

```
<a class="button" href="script to delete">delete unwanted data</a>
```

Comment: do you recommend I use mysqli? or mysql simply,

Comment: I recommend you use mysqli because mysqli is object oriented and mysql is deprecated in [php 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)

Comment: certainly! Thanks very much.